# Multithreading Java Socket

Tags: java

I have been asked to take this post down, and in particular the code, by a superior of mine

Problem 1: Client did not receive message
Solution: Make sure port matches sending's port

Problem 2: Could not broadcast message
Solution: Use a broadcast address

Comment: *I'm not quite sure i'm doing wrong here...* 
Is not very descriptive. What's the problem with what you have implemented so far?

Comment: Oh sorry for the vagueness. It seems that the packet is sent but it's not received by the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Client REceive
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 4002));


// ClientSEnd
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
socket = new DatagramSocket();  
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
```

Comment: Awesome! That resolved the "Address is in use" error and it allowed me to send and print out the message. It prints out the message that was sent and this is great progress as i'm able to see that the client actually sends a packet and can also receive it (it prints out the received message). The problem left is now that other clients within the network aren't receiving the message and i'm not sure why. I assumed using that localhost address would resolve this. hmmm

Comment: When you say other clients within the network...what do you mean by that..are you trying to run ClientReceive from other machines??

Comment: Sorry about not upvoting. I'm new to stack and it states i need 15 RP, which i don't have.

Yes, you're right. I'm trying to run "Client" on different machines so it too can receive the message being sent. It's basically a chat program where all sent messages are displayed.

Comment: no issues about not upvoting..see when you are on network you would need ip address to identify the machine...so check the ipconfig on command prompt, get the ipaddress of machine and try using that to connect from different machines...this is just suggestion dont have code for this...

Comment: you might have to use MulticastSocket and your machine IP might not work....i will paste the code shortly....hope it works on your machine

Comment: Just to make sure...in the code that I have pasted...run ClientSend on one machine first and then run ClientReceive on a different machine...then try typing text on ClientSend app

Comment: Ye, the multicast worked perfectly. http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html is the reference i used.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the port number to the Datagram socket in the receive. it will work fine.

Class - ClientReceive:

```
  DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(4001);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that did not work. I'd get an error stating "Address already in use: cannot bind"

Comment: the program might be already running in your IDE. please terminate it and try again. You can find your running programs in your console.

Comment: @user3503407 Well that's still huge progress. So start troubleshooting from there.

Comment: i agree! it definitely allowed me to move 1 step closer to my goal. Thaanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the reuse address to true ..
that will make use of the address whatever it is 4001 4002..etc

socket.setReuseAddress(true);

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that DatagramSocket allows you to send a datagram to a given destination. In your case you are sending to localhost, so that all messages are sent to the local machine only and not to other clients. If you want to reach all network clients should use a broadcast address or use the MulticastSocket class instead DatagramSocket.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. For some reason i thought "localhost" was the broadcast address for a local network. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClientSend implements Runnable
{
    private Thread t;
    private DatagramSocket socket;

    private String name;
    private String sendingMessage;
    private int port;


    public ClientSend(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try{

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);

            while(true)
            {
                sendingMessage = br.readLine();
                byte sendingData[] = sendingMessage.getBytes();

                InetAddress clientAddress = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.3");
                DatagramPacket sendingPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendingData, sendingData.length, clientAddress, 4011);

                socket.send(sendingPacket);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception       
    {   

        ClientSend CS = new ClientSend(4011);
        CS.start();
    }

}
```

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClientReceive implements Runnable
{
    private Thread t;

```
public ClientReceive()
{

}

public void run()
{
    try {

        // DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);

        MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(4011);
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("10.10.222.120");
        socket.joinGroup(group);

        //socket.setReuseAddress(true);

        //socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("10.10.222.120", 4011));

        while(true)                
        {
            byte receivingData[] = new byte[1024];

            DatagramPacket receivingPacket = new DatagramPacket(receivingData, receivingData.length);
            socket.receive(receivingPacket);




            String receivingMessage = new String(receivingPacket.getData(), 0, receivingPacket.getLength());
            System.out.println("Received: " + receivingMessage);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

public void start()
{
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception       
{   

    ClientReceive CR = new ClientReceive();
    CR.start();

}
```

}